# adjust plot given screen size with reactive value

Tags: r, shiny, flexdashboard

I am trying to adjust plots in flexdashboard by taking the pixelratio provided by the user session, this works fine when I am rendering plot with renderPlot but I am struggling to assign dynamic heights / widths to plots that are rendered with renderPlotly

I extract the user pixel ratio as followed

```
pixelratio <- reactive({
  session$clientData$pixelratio
})
```

attempt 1

```
output$myplot <- renderPlotly(myplot())
plotlyOutput("myplot", height = function() {900 / pixelratio()}, width = 825)
```

the first attempt is giving the following error msg :

```
Error : CSS units must be single element numeric or character vector
```

attempt 2

```
output$myplot <- renderPlotly(myplot())
plotlyOutput("myplot", height = 900 / pixelratio(), width = 825)
```

the second attempt is submitting the following error msg:

```
Error : Operation not allowed without an active reactive context.
* You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive consumer
```

Is there a way to get pixelratio in order to autoscale plotlyOutput?

Comment: Try `plotlyOutput("myplot", height = 900 / pixelratio(), width = 825)` in a `renderUI`, and then use `uiOutput` on the `ui` side.

Comment: You wrote that you wanted to go based on screen size, but you chose pixels. You could try percent. Additionally, depending on how you implement it and what you implement (since you didn't provide all of the details), you could try to use `vh` and `vw` (viewport height and viewport width, respectively). Viewport scaling is another method to implement percentage as a measure.

Comment: @Kat - using the percentage doesn't scale up as expected, this is why i prefer multiply a fixed width/height by the pixelratio or another coefficient

Comment: @YBS I have tried your solution and it works but it takes more time to render my plot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the height in the `plotl_ly` function and set `height = "auto"` in plotlyOutput.

```r
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)

state <- data.frame(state.x77, state.region, state.abb) %>% 
  rename(Region = state.region) %>% 
  rownames_to_column("State")


ui <- fluidPage(
  br(),
  plotlyOutput("myplotly", width = 825, height = "auto")
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  
  pixelratio <- reactive({
    session$clientData$pixelratio
  })
  
  output[["myplotly"]] <- renderPlotly({
    plot_ly(
      data = state,
      x = ~ Income,
      y = ~ Murder,
      type = "scatter",
      mode = "markers",
      text = ~ paste(State, "<br>Income: ", Income, '<br>Murder Rate:', Murder),
      height = 900 / pixelratio()
    )
    
  })
  
  observe({
    print(pixelratio())
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```